# Route [listadopresos] not defined IN laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I wanted to add a link to another page in a view, but I get the following error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2TCu.png)

**this is my web.php the route "listadopresos" doesn´t works**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomAuthController;

Route::get('dashboard', [CustomAuthController::class, 'dashboard']); 
Route::get('listadopresos', [CustomAuthController::class, 'listado']);
Route::get('login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('custom-login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customLogin'])->name('login.custom'); 
Route::get('registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'registration'])->name('register-user');
Route::post('custom-registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customRegistration'])->name('register.custom'); 
Route::get('signout', [CustomAuthController::class, 'signOut'])->name('signout');
```

**In de CustomAuthController i have this function to return de "listadopresos" view**

```
    public function listado(){
       
            return view('listadopresos');

    }
```

**and in dashboard.blade.php the file with the link i want to redirect to the listadopresos.blade.php**

```
    <a  class="btn aviso" href="javascript:window.open('{{ route('listadopresos')}}','','width=600,height=600,left=50,top=50,toolbar=yes');void 0">Listado</a>
```

**I don't know what I can do to fix it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your routes add name for your route

for example like this

```
Route::get('listadopresos', [CustomAuthController::class, 'listado'])->name('listadopresos');
```

or you can change your blade like below

```
<a  class="btn aviso" href="javascript:window.open('{{ URL('listadopresos')}}','','width=600,height=600,left=50,top=50,toolbar=yes');void 0">Listado</a>
```

Comment: This works, but when the page redirect to te "listadopresos" view this throw 404 NOT FOUND error,  and tried to make sure that the name of the sight was correct.

Comment: sometimes it dose the try running `php artisan optimize`

Comment: if running `php artisan optimize` not work change your blade back to what you wrote in the first place